# Angular-Calendar (mattlewis92) custom styling

Tags: angular, calendar

I've been using this calendar https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar for some time now, i tried to style it a bit, but only way i could influence it with css is by adding it into core css file (angular-calendar.css) in node modules.. I dont think this is the right way, but is it the only way?

Btw. localization not working on week view its still shows as "Week 45 of 2017". Any1 fixed this?

Comment: Just write some custom css and include the css in your application. E.g. write a "mystyles.css" file, add `body: { background: purple }` and `require('../path/to/mystyles.css')` in your app.

Comment: For issues pertaining to this library you should post them as Issues on Github. Taking a look at the styles, the library creator didn't make it so you could theme these styles without providing your own overrides for each style. Again, I would make an issue in Github

Comment: @duhaime thanks pal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For styling, comment by @duhaime worked for me..

And localization problem I fixed like this:

```
export class CustomDateFormatter extends CalendarDateFormatter {
  public weekViewTitle({ date, locale }: DateFormatterParams): string {
    const year: string = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
      year: 'numeric'
    }).format(date);
    const weekNumber: number = getISOWeek(date);


     return `Sedmica ${weekNumber} od ${year}`;
      }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'rokovnik',
  providers: [NotesService,  {
    provide: CalendarDateFormatter,
    useClass: CustomDateFormatter
  } ],
  templateUrl: './rokovnik.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rokovnik.component.scss']
})`
```

So I added this custom class above component where I use calendar, and put it in providers like that. For your own needs just do same and customize string that is returned >>`Week ${weekNumber} of ${year}`<<.. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

From the library documentation,

> No component styles are included with each component to make it easier to override them (otherwise you’d have to use !important on every rule that you customised). Thus you need to import the CSS file separately from node_modules/angular-calendar/dist/css/angular-calendar.css.

So (I guessing without testing), in your component you can use

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-commponent',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    'node_modules/angular-calendar/dist/css/angular-calendar.css', 
    './my.component.css'
  ]
})
```

Having your styles last should mean they override the library styles.